# Risk and uncertainty

Tags: microeconomics

A risk averse is given this: Option1: 1000 with p=0.25 and 100 with p=0.75. Option 2: 325 for sure. Which option would he choose?
For this part, I know the person will choose option 2 over option 1.
However, the question continues,change to $320 for sure, what would be his choice?

Anyone can guide?please

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a homework question without effort shown.

Comment: @FooBar Please la I have shown my answer for first part because the risk averse individual prefers safer option with same value than riskier option with same value. However, I am not sure second part

Comment: There is insufficient information to answer. You need additional information about the preferences, such as the consumer's Neumann-Morgenstern utility function or other choices. Also, FooBar was correct: you should always immediately state that what you are posting is a homework question, and then show effort in the question itself, not in a comment afterwards. You should edit your question accordingly.

Comment: This question can be reopened as noted if it is edited to meet community standards. Please consider adding additional information, and further explaining your work.